# Start PostgreSQL server manually and set verbose mode to see all queries

Tags: postgresql, macos

Is there a verbosity mode to get the list of queries executed on a PostgreSQL server in a terminal console when postgresql server is started manually? If yes, how to use it?

I'm starting the PostgreSQL server this way on macos:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/postgres -D "/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-12" -p 5432
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `log_statement=all`, either in postgresql.conf or on the `bin/postgres` command line with `-c`.